# Retrieve data from same table in all server databases

Tags: sql-server, database, data-retrieval, multi-database

I have SQL Server 2012 with DB1 , DB2 , Db3 ...> DB50

If I need to view databases in server I use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

All databases have same table `Saves` except for five databases that do not have this table.

I need to know which databases have table `Saves` - for this I use

```
sp_msforeachdb "SELECT '?' DatabaseName, Name FROM ?.sys.Tables WHERE Name LIKE '%saves%'"
```

How do I retrieve data from table `Saves` from all databases if found?

I use one by one and it takes a lot of time to save data like

```
select * from db1.dbo.Saves
```

and save data then back to search

```
select * from db2.dbo.Saves
```

and save data then back to search

```
select * from db3.dbo.Saves
```

I need a SQL command like :

```
Select * from Saves in  sys.databases  if found
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy ...

```
DECLARE @name  VARCHAR(50), -- database name  
        @Query  NVARCHAR(500) -- My Query

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
set @Query ='USE  '+@name+' 
            Go 
            if OBJECT_ID(''['+@name+'].[dbo].[saves]'') is not null
            begin
                select * from ['+@name+'].[dbo].[saves]
            end
            else
            begin
                select ''table saves does not exist into database: '+@name+''' 
            end'

/* the next line for resloving error : Incorrect syntax near 'Go'*/
SET @Query = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Query, '''', ''''''), 'GO', ''');     EXEC(''') + ''');'--Just add this one line.

exec sp_executesql @Query

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: thanks very much it's working fine but didn't show what database name

Comment: Can ad name for database that found  & Working fine from MSSQL management but when using from web site page i design it to run sql command work with other command but not this code

Comment: ( retrieve first row only from results ) in web executing

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for result.

`EXEC sp_msforeachdb '`
`USE [?];`
`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T WHERE T.TABLE_NAME=''Saves'')`
`BEGIN`
`DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);`
`SELECT @QUERY = COALESCE(@QUERY+'';`
`SELECT ''''?'''' AS DBNAME; SELECT ''''?'''' AS DBNAME,* FROM [''+T.TABLE_CATALOG+''].''+''[''+T.TABLE_SCHEMA+'']''+''.[''+T.TABLE_NAME+'']'',''`
`SELECT ''''?'''' AS DBNAME;`
`SELECT ''''?'''' AS DBNAME,* FROM [''+T.TABLE_CATALOG+''].''+''[''+T.TABLE_SCHEMA+'']''+''.[''+T.TABLE_NAME+'']'')`
`FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = ''Saves''`
`EXEC (@QUERY);`
`END`
`';`

`

Comment: thanks very much it's working fine and show the name of the database who it his table thanks again

Comment: Working fine from MSSQL management but when using from web site page i design it to run sql command work with other command but not this code

Comment: ( retrieve first row only from results  )  in web executing